# Set scroll bar in third party API using CSS

Tags: scroll, overflow

[image]

In these image,the image which is in green color is not fully displayed.Because I am using third party API for these design. That third party API does not contain scroll bar in it. So, I create scroll bar using css3. After creating custom scroll bar third party API is not supported properly on full page. So these is my problem.
Is there any way I can solve this problem using CSS.

Comment: please post the code you already tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ohk i got your question that you added scrollbar on css but it not work on green images. (y) now you have to check that which div or tag you target scrollbar. you have to check which content or div that you want to scroll automatically so you have to find class name or div tag apply scrollbar on it. you applied scrollbar at wrong place so check code again :) or give me code of it so i will correct it